# Trouble specifying name for column in SQL query result

Tags: sql

I have been asked this question for an assignment:

Find those pairs of PC models that have both the same speed and RAM. A pair should be listed
only once e.g. if `(I,j)` is listed, do not list `(j,i).`
Result:

```
PC1.model PC2.model

1004      1012
```

The following code that I wrote:

```
SELECT distinct PC1.model, PC2.model
FROM PC PC1,PC PC2
WHERE PC1.model < PC2.model and PC1.speed = PC2.speed and PC1.ram = PC2.ram;
```

Gives me the answer:

```
MODEL MODEL

1004  1012
```

However my the two column names were supposed to be `PC1.model and PC2.model`.

I tried changing my code to the code below

```
SELECT distinct PC1.model as 'PC1.model', PC2.model as 'PC2.model'
FROM PC PC1,PC PC2
WHERE PC1.model < PC2.model and PC1.speed = PC2.speed and PC1.ram = PC2.ram;
```

, but I keep getting an error:

> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 30
>   Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
>   *Cause:    
>   *Action:

I've tried everything I can, I just want to rename my columns but I can't seem to find a way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you renaming your columns in the query you have shared. What you are doing is `seleection`. Updating table is a very different thing which requires `alter` keyword

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say that I want the column names of the result to be different than they are in the table. With my previous code both column names output as "MODEL", but I want the first column to say PC1.model and the second to say PC2.model. I tried changing this by saying:SELECT distinct PC1.model as 'PC1.model', PC2.model as 'PC2.model' but this gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
  SELECT distinct PC1.model as "PC1.model", PC2.model as "PC2.model"
    FROM PC PC1,PC PC2
    WHERE PC1.model < PC2.model and PC1.speed = PC2.speed and PC1.ram = PC2.ram;
```

Comment: #CSgirl is using single quote and here its using double quote for "PC1.model" and "PC2.model",  #NineBerry already pointing the same